# How do you run an XPath contains() on a collection?

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I have an XML document whose structure is similar to the following:

```
<list>
  <item>
    <delivery>
      <date>2014-12-31T00:00:00.000Z</date>
      <!-- ... -->
    </delivery>
    <!-- ... -->
  </item>
  <item>
    <delivery>
      <date>2014-12-31T01:10:11.000Z</date>
    </delivery>
  </item>
  <item>
    <delivery>
      <date>2014-12-31T12:30:15.059Z</date>
    </delivery>
  </item>
</list>
```

What I want to do is check the deliveries are all on the same day.
What I did in SoapUI 5 (the free OSS community edition) was check the following is true:

```
contains(/list/item[*]/delivery/date, "2014-12-31")
```

SoapUI then complains you can't hand contains() a collection. Fair enough.
I then tried

```
/list/item[*]/delivery/date[contains(., "2014-12-31")]
```

but that seems to return the first date in its entirety: 2014-12-31T00:00:00.000Z

So, how can I run a contains on my collection? Alternatively, how can I check the days are the same for all deliveries?

Comment: Which XPath spec does soapui implement?

Comment: SoapUI uses [net.sf.saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) v9.1, which seems to support XPath 2.0 in its free version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is check the deliveries are all on the same day

Since you say in a comment that you have XPath 2.0 available, then how about

```
count(distinct-values(
  for $date in /list/item/delivery/date return substring($date, 1, 10)
)) = 1
```

in other words, take the date part of the date-and-time of each delivery and remove duplicates, if you end up with exactly one item left then you know all the dates were the same.

Answer (score 1):

I hope an XPath that return `<dellivery>`s having `<date>` value contains a specific date can help you validate whether *the days are the same for all deliveries* :

```
/list/item/delivery[date[contains(., "2014-12-31")]]
```

I don't know SoapUI so I can only suggest an XPath only work-around :

```
count(/list/item/delivery[date[not(contains(., "2014-12-31"))]])
```

If above XPath return `0` means all days are the same; `2014-12-31`.

Comment: I want an XPath only solution, so I need something XPath that does the "looping through all elements" for me (or uses e.g. count() to get around that).

Answer (score 1):

XPath is not able to do any kind of looping. You would have to fake this out by, as you pointed out, using counts.

Your XPath expression would be:

```
count(//*:date[text()='${#Response#//*:date}'])
```

This says: count the number of dates, that have the same date as the first one.

Your expected result would be:

```
${#Response#count(//*:date)}
```

This says: count the number of all dates.

Comment: Hi @SiKing, do you have any recommended reading to be able to decipher that, piece by piece? it's the first time I've seen a hash/pound/# sign in XPath. Or is that SoapUI's property expansion?

Comment: SoapUI's property expansion.

Comment: It mostly works (the date field unfortunately holds more than just the day, so it'd need substrings) - though I'm still struggling to figure out why. `//*` means: select any element. I'm not sure what the colon does; I don't think we're defining a namespace? We then pick the date elements where the elements' content is equal to the first date element's content. (Why is the same Xpath once returning a collection and once the first element?) Last nut not least, we count them and compare the count of matching elements to the overall count of date elements.

Comment: I think you have a lot to learn about XPath. Start here: http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Comment: That's an understatement... ;-) Thank you for the link! :)

Comment: I skimmed through the page, but I still don't know why you used a single instead of a double colon... :( Can I get another hint, please?

Comment: Single colon separates namespace:element. I am using the asterix to select _any_ namespace. Double colon separates axis::element.

Comment: I've only looked at http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp so far, so please forgive me for being rather naive, but: why the double slash before the asterisk, then? The [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) say `// is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/`. Is a namespace considered a node, too?